# How can I obtain the same vertical space between the chapter number and the chapter title?

Tags: spacing, header-footer

How can I obtain the same vertical space between the chapter number and the chapter title for all chapters? The space between the chapter number and the chapter title reduces when the title goes on more than one line. In this case I want to have the same space as the case when the title is one line.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Vertical Spacing}
\end{document}
```

The `thesis.sty` file is given below.

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0cm} \setlength{\headheight}{.8cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{.4cm} \setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15 cm} 
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1cm}  

\def\chapter{\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\secdef\CHAPa\CHAPb}
\def\CHAPa[#1]#2{%
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\chaptername{\protect\ \thechapter: #1}}%

\renewcommand{\KM}{#2} 
{{\centering \chaptername\ \thechapter \par}
  { \centering #2\par}}
  \vspace{\baselineskip}}
\def\CHAPb#1{%
  { \centering #1\par}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\KM}{Introduction} 
\newcommand{\sectionThesis}[1]{\renewcommand{\KM}{\sf #1}\section{#1}}


\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
          {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
                          {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}     

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
```

Comment: An MWE would be helpful to those trying to help you.  At this point, we don't even know what document class you are using.

Comment: @Peter I cannot use thesis package. Is it tied to your university? Or link?

Comment: It is probably linked to the thesis package, because it isn't the default behaviour nor what titlesec does.

Comment: Where can we find a copy of `thesis.sty`? Otherwise any solution might not work as expected if it is based on the default [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) document class...

Comment: @Bernard. I got the thesis.sty file from my supervisors, but I do not know where they got it.

Comment: I'm afraid no one can do anything without it, as the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @Bernard. `thesis.sty` is 34 lines. Can I edit my original post and put it after `end{document}`?

Comment: Personally I see no objection. However, I think I've found it on CTAN. If it is that one (it also has very few lines),  it just says it's obsolete and must be replaced by thesis.cls… that has 1120 lines. To be sure, check the content: the author should be `Wenzel Matiaske`.

Comment: @PeterPalmer: Based on the contents of `thesis.sty` there is no difference in the vertical spacing when a chapter title spans one *or* two lines. So I don't think there is much more to say.

Comment: @PeterPalmer yeah I don't see any changes. Maybe other packages are causing the problems.

Comment: @Werner. Originally I wanted a single space between multi-line chapter titles, so for some chapters I used `\singlespacing` for the title. I now have a consistent space between the chapter number and chapter title because I put `\singlespacing` in all chapters. Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close as the solutions seems to have benn using the same markup for all chapters, so basically it's a typo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as the solution seems to have benn using the same markup for all chapters, so basically it's a typo.